# variable assignment and synthesizable code

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesize

Simply having a code like this :

```
if(rising_edge(clk)) then
    temp(0):="001";
    temp(1):="011";
    temp(2):="101";
    temp(3):="000";
    temp(0):=temp(3)xor temp(5);
end if
```

For the example above all this variable assignment would be done in 1 clock cycle which is pretty unpractical. In the behavioral simulation it works fine but in post synthesis it's messed up. Can I add like a delay or a sth like a wait(wait statement is un-synthesizable) to make it wait util the variable gets its value before jumping to the next line?

Comment: what do you mean by "messed up"? what do the results look like? where's temp(5) coming from in your posted code?

Answer (score 0):

Doing all of those things in one clock cycle is simple. Hardware is extremely fast, and FPGA clock rates aren't that high relative to processors.

Since you are using variables, the intermediate results are used immediately.  If you want a more explicit delay, you could use a signal.  The above code with signals would use `temp(3)` from the previous rising edge.

Answer (score 0):

for synthesis you can not make delays like wait. well defined, controllable delays in synthesis can only be made with pipelining (clock cycles as delay units).